# Refresh a View Controller

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

In my app delegate, I have this method that gets stubbed out automatically, to do something when a view controller gets selected.

If the type of the viewController is SavedViewController, then it's a UITableView subclass, and I would like to refresh the table. However, this code doesn't work:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
  if([viewController isKindOfClass: [SavedViewController class]]) {
    [viewController.tableView reloadData];
  }
}
```

The error I get is "request for tableView is something not a structure or union. Within the SavedViewController class, I can do this just fine:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

So, what am I doing wrong in my function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch this line:

```
[viewController.tableView reloadData];
```

To this:

```
[[(SavedViewController *)viewController tableView] reloadData];
```

Comment: I think you are right, but after putting in some log statements, I don't think the function is ever getting called. This method must not be for what I think it's for?

Comment: I figured out the last bit... needed to set the delegate of the tabBarController.

Answer (score 0):

try casting to a uitableviewcontroller